# Change the opacity/transparency of a view and affect the child views too

Tags: android, android-layout, opacity, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout with child `TextView`s.
The background of the parent `RelativeLayout` is white and I was wondering how I could change the alpha to change the opacity of the whole view programmatically (including children).
I am trying:

```
getBackground().setAlpha(0.4);
```

But that expects an int and not a float.
If I do:

```
getBackground().setAlpha((int)(0.4 * 255));
```

The latter changes the view but makes it darker than I want. Also the children do not seem to change. It seems to affect only the background while I want something that makes everything more "grayed" out/less transparent.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you **are changing the backgound** of the layout and not the layout itself. So instead of `myRelativeLayout.getBackground().setAlpha()`, use this: `myRelativeLayout.setAlpha(0.4f)`.

Comment: By the way why in one case the alpha is expected int and the other float?

Comment: To be clear to the OP's question: using `setAlpha` affects the view and all it's child views.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `android:background="#88000000"` in layout file. You can change alpha and color values as required.

Comment: I am setting color as `#FFFFFF`

Comment: if you want to set alpha, you need to write color in #ARRGGBB format

Comment: Should it be then `88FFFFFF`?

Comment: I mean isn't what you defined black? How should I use that?

Comment: That won't work, because you are again changing the **background** of the layout, just in a different way. The children won't be affected by this.

Comment: So I should set it initially to `#8800000` then how can I make it like `FFFFFF` when I want and set the alpha the other cases? This view is in a list

Comment: @Jim try my answer.

Comment: But I don't understand how. If I set the background to `#88000000` then if how do I set it to pure white with 80% less opacity?